# How to use encrypted TenSEAL ckksvectors in Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, encryption, deep-learning

I am trying to encrypt my data using the TenSEAL library in python by following a tutorial(https://github.com/OpenMined/TenSEAL/blob/main/tutorials/Tutorial%202%20-%20Working%20with%20Approximate%20Numbers.ipynb)

I have converted my arrays to lists for ckks vectors to work and run encryption on them like so:

```
X_traintf = X_train.tolist()
X_testtf = X_train.tolist()
y_traintf = y_train.tolist()
y_testtf = y_train.tolist()

t_start = time()
enc_x_test = [ts.ckks_vector(ctx_eval, x) for x in X_testtf]
enc_y_test = [ts.ckks_vector(ctx_eval, y) for y in y_testtf]
t_end = time()
print(f"Encryption of the test-set took {int(t_end - t_start)} seconds")
```

then I tried to use them as inputs for my tensorflow model and got this error:

```
model.fit(enc_x_train, enc_y_train,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(enc_x_test, enc_y_test))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(enc_x_train, enc_y_train,
      2           epochs=epochs,
      3           validation_data=(enc_x_test, enc_y_test))

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py:1105, in select_data_adapter(x, y)
   1102 adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]
   1103 if not adapter_cls:
   1104     # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
-> 1105     raise ValueError(
   1106         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: {}, {}".format(
   1107             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)
   1108         )
   1109     )
   1110 elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
   1111     raise RuntimeError(
   1112         "Data adapters should be mutually exclusive for "
   1113         "handling inputs. Found multiple adapters {} to handle "
   1114         "input: {}, {}".format(adapter_cls, _type_name(x), _type_name(y))
   1115     )

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tenseal.tensors.ckksvector.CKKSVector'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tenseal.tensors.ckksvector.CKKSVector'>"})
```

I have also tried to convert them into tensorflow tensors like so:

```
X_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_x_train)
y_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_y_train)
X_test_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_x_test)
y_test_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_y_test)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 1
----> 1 X_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_x_train)
      2 y_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_y_train)
      3 X_test_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_x_test)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:98, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97 ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<tenseal.tensors.ckksvector.CKKSVector object at 0x7f78b8273df0>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tenseal.tensors.ckksvector.CKKSVector'>) to a Tensor.
```

Is there any way for these ckks vectors to be integrated into a tensorflow model?/